# Compile .java files or .class files in eclipse

Tags: java

I have done some changes in my .java files in eclipse...ie. I have passed one more parameter in a method..
but how to compile it so that the changes will be seen in .class files

Comment: Just Build your project again.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple clean build your project , clean removes the old class files and build creates new class files, Eclipse provides Build Automatically option , you set this check box , so that every time you change something class files are updated automatically .

Answer (score 0):

It's simple follow below steps::
* Goto Project in menu bar

[image]

- select clean from submenu. And select project you want to clean then ok.

[image]

- In above image you can configure some build options, before ok.
- if you have checked build automatically in project menu, then project build automatically. Otherwise select 'build project'.

[image]